# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 failed and system crashed

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I've upgraded my system from 14.04 to 16.04. It was taking a long time. After a long time, the system stopped working. After a 5-hour wait, I've restarted the system and now I am able to access only the shell prompt.

Comment: My system is just 1 year old

Comment: If you were not updating through command line, did you click to see what terminal was showing? You have to make several choices in the terminal, so maybe it was simply waiting until you select?